# Getting blank page when article trespasses certain amount of alpha numeric characters

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, compiler-warnings, mysql5

I've been writing an article for almost 1 month, it's a super list that has over 180+ itens, including imagens as previews. Problem is that when I reached some point, the article's page got blank. It's like there is a limit of alpha numberic characters, because if I use a smaller amount of chars, it will work. I took a look at the error log and there was this:

```
[29-Dec-2015 19:53:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: XCache: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0
[29-Dec-2015 19:53:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo.so: undefined symbol: zval_property_ctor in Unknown on line 0
[29-Dec-2015 19:53:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: pdo_sqlite: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0
[29-Dec-2015 19:53:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/sqlite.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/sqlite.so: undefined symbol: zval_property_ctor in Unknown on line 0
[29-Dec-2015 19:53:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: pdo_mysql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0
[29-Dec-2015 19:53:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: SourceGuardian: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0
[29-Dec-2015 19:53:23 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: XCache: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0
[29-Dec-2015 19:53:23 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo.so: undefined symbol: zval_property_ctor in Unknown on line 0
[29-Dec-2015 19:53:23 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: pdo_sqlite: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0
[29-Dec-2015 19:53:23 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/sqlite.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/sqlite.so: undefined symbol: zval_property_ctor in Unknown on line 0
[29-Dec-2015 19:53:23 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: pdo_mysql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0
[29-Dec-2015 19:53:23 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: SourceGuardian: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0
```

I contacted my server, they said it was problem with the php recompiler, then they analyzed it and came back saying there was no problem at all, I pushed a litte more and they said they were going to look further, then, after 1 week, they said there is a content plugin in my site that is causing this error. I've been checking this now for the past 3 hours, disabling, enabling plugins, clearing cache, and it seem that the problem isn't with the site. What might it be?

Comment: That _is_ a PHP compile/configuration problem. Since the API version the PHP core and the module were compiled against don’t match, PHP refuses to even start – so this happens way before your script could cause any problems. Who’s in charge of server configuration? Did you try and configure _anything_ yourself in that regard?

Comment: It's a shared server, I don't have direct access to apache files, but I can create my own php.ini file under the public folder, even though I'm not using a php.ini file.

Comment: Are you there. What should I do?